# Question about a chapter in Feynman's book

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

I was reading *six easy pieces* by Feynman, and I had reached the section on the [Conservation of energy](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_04.html)

This chapter was defintly one of the harder ones so far, especially considering that his reversible machines analogy made things somehow more difficult.

Anyway I pushed on, and came across something that confused me. Feynman states:

> Therefore, the principle that the sum of the heights times the weights does not change...

What exactly does this mean? Why does the product not change? Is this fact proven in that thought experiment he conducted earlier in the chapter?

Comment: without knowing what Feyman is talking about, it is impossible to say what he means. You need to explain what his statement applies to.

Comment: You need to tell us exactly where the statement in question appears in the chapter you gave us so we can see it in context.

Comment: sorry guys, i understand that without context this may be confusing. If you click on the link above, and scroll down to figure 4-6 and read the paragraph below the figure, you should be able to understand what I am talking about.

Answer (score 3):

In this passage, he's talking about a situation in *statics*, where the kinetic energy of every component is zero. This system is also non-dissipative (meaning that there are no mechanisms like friction in which energy can leak out of the system), so mechanical energy is also conserved. Mechanical energy is the sum of kinetic and potential energy:

$$E=K+V$$

Since the kinetic energy is zero in this case, this means that the mechanical energy is the same as the potential energy in this case: $E=V$. Since the mechanical energy doesn't change, and the potential energy is the same as the mechanical energy, this means that the potential energy cannot change.

The potential energy for an object with weight $mg$ at a height $h$ is $mgh$, in other words, the height times the weight. The sum of these heights times weights is the total potential energy, so that sum cannot change.

Comment: ohh ok that makes a lot more sense. Thanks for the answer